# Why I have no "retag" button on my own questions?

Tags: support, user-interface, edits

Hello,

I have both "retag" and "edit" buttons on other people's questions and may choose one of them if I need to retag or edit a question. But I have the only "edit" button for my own questions. Half of the time I need only to retag my question and I need not load whole editor.

Where is my "retag" button?

Comment: I just realized I misread this a bit; you said you have retag *and* edit buttons on some posts? Which posts? (I have no idea what you mean by "alien questions")

Comment: @Michael I imagine that "alien" in this case is just an elaborate way to describe a question posted by someone other than the author. More colorful than "on other people's questions"

Comment: @Michael I figured out what the author is referring to. See the update I'm about to put in my answer.

Comment: @Michael - sorry for my english, edited

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This has the same roots as to why [Community Wiki posts do not have retag links](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/60791/why-isnt-there-a-retag-link-on-community-wiki-questions) - you never have simultaneous retag and edit permissions on a single question. You only have the retag link when you lack the sufficient permissions to do a full edit - so only for other people's posts when you have 500-1999 reputation. On your own posts, it'll always be edit since you'll always have that permission. And, once you hit 2000 reputation, you'll only ever see `edit` links and not another `retag` link.

---

Currently, you can see both retag and edit on questions as part of a new mechanic on Stack Overflow exclusively that lets you submit potential edits when having less than 2000 reputation. There are two separate links because when you have between 500-1999, you can use the "retag" link to perform a retag without needing to go through the validation process. While it does load a smaller form, that's not the technical reason behind its presence.

Once you hit 2000 reputation, then as mentioned earlier you'll only have an edit link. This doesn't really change much for your own questions because you also don't need validation of your edits to your own posts.

Comment: Oh, of course. Good call

Comment: @Michael Eh, you share in some of the glory of this. I'dn't've figured it out if I hadn't thought about how you have >2k whereas I have <2k. That confirms how the retag would disappear at 2k.

Comment: I understood the theory, it is clear. But I steel need a "retag" button if I only need to retag (not full edit) my question independently from my number of points.

Comment: @developer You don't need one, you can edit tags at the bottom of the edit window. If you want the retag page to always be available for some reason you might want to convert this to a feature-request, but it's probably unlikely to happen